# Delete rows of data in batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to this so please be gentle. I need to delete millions of rows of data in two tables. When I tried this with a sql script,the log file got so big that it took up all of hard drive and did not complete. I was reading a few articles online that said, if the data was deleted in batches that the log file would not be affected in the same way. The database in currently in simple mode and is always kept that way. this is the script I use to delete the data.

```
Delete from EligibilityInformation Where DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
Delete from EligibilityRequestLog Where ActualPostingDate <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
```

Can someone help me with a script that I can add as a SQL Job that will delete 10,000 rows of data at a time until all the rows have been deleted?I found the following script online. It may be more than I need. I added my SQL script to it.

```
DECLARE @continue INT
DECLARE @rowcount INT

SET @continue = 1
WHILE @continue = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT GETDATE()
    SET ROWCOUNT 10000
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    Delete from EligibilityInformation Where DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
    Delete from EligibilityRequestLog Where ActualPostingDate <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
    SET @rowcount = @@rowcount 
    COMMIT
    PRINT GETDATE()
    IF @rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @continue = 0
    END
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Each SQL dialect is different, and each engine behaves in a different manner.  Looks like MS SQL Server, but (if so) which version?  If it's 2008+ then you can use `TOP` to delete only 10,000 rows, and loop until no rows are deleted...  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175486(v=sql.105).aspx  Also, why is the script that you have found not suitable for your needs?

Comment: It's SQL 2014. I don't know that the script would work. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Errrrrrrrr, then try it?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it

Comment: What does the to of this script mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EligibilityInformation WHERE DateEntered <= DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    PRINT GETDATE()
    DELETE (TOP 10000) FROM EligibilityInformation WHERE DateEntered <= DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
    PRINT GETDATE()
END

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EligibilityRequestLog WHERE ActualPostingDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    PRINT GETDATE()
    DELETE (TOP 10000) FROM EligibilityRequestLog WHERE ActualPostingDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
    PRINT GETDATE()
END
```

Comment: Not sure you need `PRINT GETDATE()` twice per loop.  The second print of one iteration will pretty much match the first print of the next itteration.  Also, using `@@rowcount` to control the loop (did I delete anything) is cheaper than the `EXISTS` method.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at the server right now to test this syntax but this is something I use

```
select 1  -- to get a @@rowcount > 0 
while (@@rowcount > 0) 
begin 
   delete (top 1000) from table where ...
end
```

Putting the two in a transaction is just a LOT of overhead where I see no value.  At best you would roll back a single set (top).  If you tired to wrap the loop in single transaction then doing it in sets adds nothing.

the script you have now is nothing more than

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
Delete from EligibilityInformation Where DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
Delete from EligibilityRequestLog Where ActualPostingDate <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a primary key.  This should work for you:

```
Delete Top 10000  
    From EligibilityInformation Where DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
```

Here is an article on why you might choose Top over Set Rowcount
https://sqlstudies.com/2013/10/07/use-top-instead-of-set-rowcount/

Comment: Maybe for SQL Server 2000, but for SQL Server 2008 onwards, it just needs to be `DELETE TOP(10000) FROM EligibilityInformation WHERE DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())` no self join or sub-query required.  Or even, use the `@@rowcount` "trick" that the Op has already.  But what isn't yet clear is why the Op's example code is insufficient for the Op's needs.

Comment: When I posted my answer there was no version specified.  I see his comment now so I will edit.

Comment: Nice link!  The impact on triggers was not something I remembered, very important.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the row count below 5,000, I normally use 4,000, so that you can skip lock escalation. It normally runs faster, and has less contention.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of the above answers for clearing audit tables.

```
select 1
while (@@ROWCOUNT >0)
begin
    delete TOP (4000)   from [Audit_database].[dbo].[table] where audTimeStamp <=DateAdd(day,-365,getdate())
end
```

So for your table it would be

```
select 1
while (@@ROWCOUNT >0)
begin
   delete TOP (4000) from EligibilityInformation Where DateEntered <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
end

select 1
while (@@ROWCOUNT >0)
begin
    Delete TOP (4000) from EligibilityRequestLog Where ActualPostingDate <= DateAdd(day,-31, getdate())
end
```