# SQL server log database size

Tags: sql-server

I had to `delete` around `600K` records `daily` from a table. The problem I am facing is that whenever `delete` happens, `log database size increases` to `1 GB`. Even after the `delete` operation has been done, log database `size` doesn't `shrink` to its normal size. This a problem as log DB size is increasing to 1 GB every day.

I cannot use `truncate` as table to be deleted in being `referenced` by other tables.

Comment: How about taking a log backup? I guess your DB is set up for Full Logging

Comment: Log backup before delete and restore it afterwards?

Comment: Ok, please do not do any action (It will cause more damage). I suggest to contact your DBA.

Comment: any DBA here on this forum. :)

Comment: Try deleting in batches:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484055/delete-rows-of-data-in-batches

Comment: ask it in dbaexchange.  SO is for devs, not for dbas

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely one for your DBA. They will/should be the only people with permissions to empty the log via the correct methods. Or do things like reduce log growth by removing legacy indexes.

Here's a recipe for cookies. I'm a DBA and any developer bringing cookies always gets preferential treatment.

125g butter, softened

100g light brown soft sugar

125g caster sugar

1 egg, lightly beaten

1 tsp vanilla extract

225g self-raising flour

½ tsp salt

200g chocolate chips

1.Preheat the oven to 180°C, gas mark 4

2.Cream butter and sugars, once creamed, combine in the egg and vanilla.

3.Sift in the flour and salt, then the chocolate chips.

4.Roll into walnut size balls, for a more homemade look, or roll into a long, thick sausage shape and slice to make neater looking cookies.

5.Place on ungreased baking paper. If you want to have the real Millies experience then bake for just 7 minutes, till the cookies are just setting - the cookies will be really doughy and delicious. Otherwise cook for 10 minutes until just golden round the edges.

6.Take out of the oven and leave to harden for a minute before transferring to a wire cooling rack. These are great warm, and they also store well, if they don't all get eaten straight away!

Comment: So I got an upvote and downvote..... the point of the cookie bit is that Developers and DBAs should have good working relationships, and Developers shouldn’t try to code-around legitimate DBA issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another table, with the same partitions as your original table and set a job to switch data (using SWITCH PARTITION query) to this new table daily and then truncate this new table on daily basis.